# How to get pagelength and displayStart value on controller from jquery datatable?

Tags: datatable, datatables, liferay, datatables-1.10

I am using jquery datatable 1.10

Problem :- I am using jquery data-table with server side processing but on controller side i am not able to get pageLength and displayStart everytime it is 0. Can any one please help me to figure it out?

```
I am using below mentioned code of script

$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#orderTable').DataTable({ 
"processing": true, 
"serverSide": true, 
"searching": true, 
"paging": true, 
"pageLength": 5, 
"lengthChange": true, 
"lengthMenu": [ [5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"] ], 
"pagingType": "full_numbers", 
"displayStart": 10, 
"ajax": { 
      "url":"${getOrderURL}",
      "dataSrc": "response", 
      "type": "POST" 
}, 
"columns": [ 
       {"data": "key", "orderable": true },
       { "data": "short_title", "orderable": true }, 
       { "data": "title", "orderable": false },
       { "data": "description", "orderable": false } 
     ]
  });
});
```

controller code :-

```
Integer start=ParamUtil.getInteger(resourceRequest, "pageLength"); 
System.out.println("start : "+start);
System.out.println("length : "+ParamUtil.getInteger(resourceRequest, "displayStart"));
```

Thanks in Advance,

Thanks & Regards,

Ravi Darji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resourceRequest` can not come with requested parameter

need to convert request in original `servlet` request

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(resourceRequest));
```

with `httpServletRequest` you can get it now instead of `resourceRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters are available to the server side by parameter names as **length** and **start** respectively.

For more reference of all the server side parameters which are available while requesting, check out the datatable documentation in the link https://datatables.net/manual/server-side